# Gluon Scene Builder: Custom controls from source code

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Is there a way to use custom controls with Scene Builder if the controls are not yet built but part of the application's source code?

Comment: There is a new feature in Scene Builder based on this [PR](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/pull/228), that allows adding a folder with .class files (i.e your target/classes or build/classes folder). Since this feature is not release yet, you will need to build SB yourself from the repository.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

As a little side-node: On has to love this statement in the build instructions for SceneBuilder: "Gluon Scene Builder is frequently released, [..]", maybe this should be removed from there ;-)

Comment: @JoséPereda Unfortunately I have issues with this feature, I created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/issues/281